# Adjective for 'shite'

Tags: single-word-requests, offensive-language, analogy, euphemisms, derivation

The adjective for *'shit'* is *'shitty'.* Is there no different adjective for the British word *'shite'?*

Comment: Shite questions can still be interesting. ;-)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The adjective form of *shite* is [*shite*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shite):

> That was a shite film.
>
> I feel shite about it.
>
> Mondays are always a bit shite.

Comment: I love the fact that somewhere on the internet people are wondering about the adjective form of *shite*.

Comment: Amazingly, our cousins in Blighty are so enamored of their shite that they use it as noun, verb, adjective and adveb. Rumor has it that a team of grammarians is working in a secret location in Battersea to turn it into a subordinating conjunction.

Comment: Just be sure that you do not, under any circumstance,  double the "i."

Comment: @Senex Rumour has it that modern sectarian problems in Syria and Iraq stem back to a misunderstanding caused by a grumpy British colonial officer with a stammer, who, in the early 20th Century, on being unable to find a gin and tonic that met his satisfaction, stutteringly declared "This is a shi...ite country!"

Comment: @Rob_Ster Early prototypes aren't promising: "Alice asked Bob to throw out the food shite it had gone."

Answer (score 18):

*Shite* has an adjective sense, so for most uses, *shite* would be the adjective.

However, this is also true of *shit*.

*Shitty* overlaps in senses with the adjective senses of *shit* and *shite*, and often if you call something *shitty* you could also call it *shit* or *shite*. However, *shitty* also has the sense "covered in shit" which *shit* and *shite* do not mean.

In some dialects there is the adjective *shitey* which has this meaning. It would be the Scots equivalent to *shitty* and hence more likely to be found in Scotland and Ulster due to the Scots and Ulster-Scots influence, though it will also be found in other places, such as some parts of Ireland without as strong an Ulster-Scots influence.

Hence in such dialects the adjective you seek is *shitey*, as in the Scots expression, "he'd drink through a shitey cloot" ("he [was so-enamoured with alcoholic beverages that if it was the only way to get a drink he] would drink through through a shit-covered rag").

Since *shitey* is not as wide-spread as *shite*, and since *shite* is just a variant of *shit*, in other dialects the adjective would be *shitty*.

Comment: For further reference, here's the [Scottish National Dictionary](https://dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/snd00090548) in the specific expression mentioned; and shitey is also in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shitey), but doesn't seem to have made any of the formally edited lexicons.